# database normalization of a table

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization

Let's consider I have the following not normalized table

1) warehouse
  
   id
   item_id
   residual
   purchase cost
   sale cost
   Currency

I tried to normalize this and I obtained this tables:

1) warehouse table
  
   id
   product_id
   residual 
   cost_id

2) costs table

id
   purchase cost
   sale cost
   Currency

Does that comply with database normal forms?

Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: a) Normalization is based on functional dependencies. What are the functional dependencies? b) Normalization never introduces new attributes, as you did with "cost_id".

Comment: Your original table looks normalized to me, assuming I correctly deduced the contents of each column from the name of the column (and I don't understand what "residual" is, but it doesn't appear to be involved in your normalization attempt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "residual" means in this context. But just ignoring that ...

I doubt that there's anything to be gained by breaking cost out into a separate table. Let's say we have two products, "toaster model 14" and "men's shirt style X7". Both have a cost of $12. So you create a cost record for $12, and point both records to this. Then you realize that you made a mistake and the toaster really cost $13. So you update the cost record. But that will then update the cost for the shirt also, which is almost surely wrong. Having a separate cost table would mean that you would always create a new cost record every time you created a stock record. Nothing is gained.

The fields you have listed look to me like they all belong in one table. You'd also need an item table that would have data like the description, maybe manufacturer, product specs, etc.

Your warehouse table appears to really be a stocked item table, as it lists items and not warehouses, but whatever. I suspect it also needs some sort of serial number, or how will you link a given physical item in the warehouse to the corresponding record?

If by "sale cost" you mean the price that you will charge to the customer when you sell it, I doubt this belongs in the warehouse table. When a customer buys a product, do you tell him, "I can sell you the one that's in bin 40 in the warehouse for $20 or the one that's in bin 42 for $22. Which do you want?" Probably not. I suspect you charge the same price regardless of which particular unit the customer gets. The fact that the price you have to pay to your supplier went up between when you bought the first one and when you bought the second one normally does not mean that you will charge your customer a different price. You may raise the price, but you will have one price regardless of which unit is sold. Therefore, the selling price goes in the item table, not the warehouse table. If "sale cost" is something else, maybe this whole paragraph is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but it's too verbose.

There's not enough information to provide an answer - we have to infer structure from context - and the context is confusing. Your initial record looks like a description of a product to be bought and sold - but you've named it as warehouse - which is a place for storing products. I've no idea what you mean by residual. Do you have multiple purchase costs for a specific product? If so how are they differentiated. Similar for sale cost. If ther are multiple costs involved why is the selling price tied to the purchase cost?

Comment: warehouse - I mean dross. Yes I have multiple sale costs and multiple purchase costs.